# Parent variable not working inside of ng-content

Tags: angular

**Intro:** I'm working on ng2 components whose structure looks like this:

```
<cards>
  <card>
    <card-content-type-1 (state)="cardState"></card-content-type-1>
  </card>
  <card>
    <card-content-type-2 (state)="cardState"></card-content-type-2>
  </card>
  <card>
    <card-content-type-3 (state)="cardState"></card-content-type-3>
  </card>
  ...
</cards>
```

And I'm changing states of each `<card>` based on click/mouseenter/mouseleave events, and when some action happen inside of `<card>` component (parent component), based on current state, I'd like to trigger some animation methods inside `<card-content-type-N>` components (children component). For sequence of animations I'll use `AnimationBuilder` and `ElementRef`.

---

**Issue:** I decided to pass parent component variable to children component, and to implement `ngOnChanges()` inside of children, which will trigger specific animation depends of current variable value. But I have troubles to pass parent variable to children when I use ng-content inside of parent template.

I created simplified example (I replaced `<card>` with `<parent-comp>`, and `<card-content-type-N>` with `<child-comp>`): https://plnkr.co/edit/OHIJjMwdx6ifRiSxsanB?p=preview

In this example `parentVar` is not passed into the `child-comp`. Is this some bug in Angular2 or I'm doing something wrong? I suppose that is related with `ng-content` scope, but we lack good docs/examples about this.

In same example inside of `src/parent-comp.ts` if we replace intial template with `<child-comp [childVar]="parentVar"></child-comp>` parent variable is passed properly.

Also inside of `src/app.ts` if we replace initial template with  this:

```
<parent-comp>
  <child-comp [childVar]="true"></child-comp>
</parent-comp>
```

static variable is passed properly.

Does someone have a similar issue? Or have idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```html
<parent-comp #parent>
  <child-comp [childVar]="parent.parentVar"></child-comp>
</parent-comp>
```

Here is the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/rVMruocy2Mhtl4yTmvio?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think decorator ContentChildren may help you on this.

```
export class ParentComp {

  @ContentChildren(ChildComp) childs: QueryList<ChildComp>

  doSth(parentVar) {
    this.childs.toArray().forEach(child=> child.childVar = parentVar);
  }

}
```

Not sure whether it is what you want.
Here is the plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Lx5IFtjMMA20WCj4P2bF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. I'll have multiple different types of child component (`card-content-type-N` in above example) and in my case `@ContentChildren` decorator will not work.