# Angular Moving methods and properties from child-component (wrapped by <ng-content>) into parent-component

Tags: angular

The `child-component`  is wrapped in the `parent-component` by means of `<ng-content>` with some methods and properties like this

> parent.component

```
<child-root>
    <!-- child header -->
    <div class="childHeader" [ngClass]="{'slideUp': !slideUpBoole}">
        <div class="properties">
            <button class="button" (click)="slideToggle()">slide toggle</button>
            <button class="button" (click)="fullScreen()">full screen</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- child body -->
    <div class="childBody" *ngIf="slideUpBoole">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="{'show': searchBoole}"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- child footer -->
    <div class="childFooter" *ngIf="slideUpBoole">
        <button class="button" (click)="search()">search</button>
    </div>
</child-root>

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-root',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent {
    /* this code use in the child.component */
    public slideUpBoole: boolean = true;
    public fullScreenBoole: boolean = false;

    public slideToggle() {
        this.slideUpBoole = !this.slideUpBoole;
    }
    public fullScreen() {
        this.fullScreenBoole = !this.fullScreenBoole;
    }
    public search() {
        console.log('do something with connected parent component');
    }
}
```

> child.component

```
<div class="child">
    <ng-content select=".childHeader"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".childBody"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".childFooter"></ng-content>
</div>

@Component({
    selector: 'child-root',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
    /* move parent-component's code into here */
}
```

In such cases Angular doesn’t  allow me to write the typescript code in the `child-component`. In what way can I write the code so as the methods and properties are included in the `child-component` or in some `service`? I want to avoid writing the typescript in the `parent-component` as much as possible in this case.

Comment: You could input them via @Input. If you want to be aware of changes you can use Observables (or such). Would make sense to wrap them in some class, so you could also emit the changed result from the child component.

Comment: @Heady my child-component I wrap into 40 different parent components, and in all of these 40 parent-components I should write the code, because of that I want write the code in the child-component one times and thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. solve like this [parent-variable-not-working-inside-of-ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425958/parent-variable-not-working-inside-of-ng-content)

> parent.component

```
<child-root #childRoot>
    <!-- child header -->
    <div class="childHeader" [ngClass]="{'slideUp': !childRoot.slideUpBoole}">
        <div class="properties">
            <button class="button" (click)="childRoot.slideToggle()">slide toggle</button>
            <button class="button" (click)="childRoot.fullScreen()">full screen</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- child body -->
    <div class="childBody" *ngIf="childRoot.slideUpBoole">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="{'show': childRoot.searchBoole}"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- child footer -->
    <div class="childFooter" *ngIf="childRoot.slideUpBoole">
        <button class="button" (click)="childRoot.search()">search</button>
    </div>
</child-root>

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-root',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent {
    /* this code use in the child.component */

}
```

> child.component

```
<div class="child">
    <ng-content select=".childHeader"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".childBody"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".childFooter"></ng-content>
</div>

@Component({
    selector: 'child-root',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
    /* move parent-component's code into here */
    public slideUpBoole: boolean = true;
    public fullScreenBoole: boolean = false;

    public slideToggle() {
        this.slideUpBoole = !this.slideUpBoole;
    }
    public fullScreen() {
        this.fullScreenBoole = !this.fullScreenBoole;
    }
    public search() {
        console.log('do something with connected parent component');
    }
}
```